# DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges is causing automatic migrations even though I haven't enabled them

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

EntityFramework 6

I'm trying to diagnose a race condition that happens when 2 separate services that start at the same time after an install use the same Context.

In both cases the Context is using a DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges initializer.

When looking through the stack trace when the race condition happens, the exception traces through DbMigrator :

```
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
 at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
 at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
```

I haven't enabled automatic migrations, and it doesn't APPEAR that they are enabled in the underlying projects for the services (there is no Migrations folder, and there are no code references to enabling automatic migrations). Is there another way to check to see if they have been enabled? I know they are happening because the database the context is referencing has a __MigrationHistory folder.

Are they enabled by default? Why are migrations happening?

Comment: Have you validated that they are not turned on in your web.config?

Comment: There is no web.config. They are not turned on in the app.config.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the `_MigrationHistory` folder and anything under it. Also check you database if it has `_MigrationHistory` table, Delete it.

Verify if AutomaticMigrationEnabled flag is false. if not set `AutomaticMigrationEnabled = false`. you can do it in configuration class constructor.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Set the database initializer to null.

```
`Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);`
```

But make sure you do it before instantiating any object of DbContext. So probably set it in Startup.cs/Global.asax etc for web. Or simply put it in the static constructor of your Context class.

```
static MyDbContext() {
    Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. How can I tell if they are on and if they are why?

Comment: If you have _MigrationHistory folder and _MigrationHistory table then it's on. There no other way or command to know that. May be you can try running the update-database command manually. It will fail if the migrations are not enabled. For why? If you are not the sole owner of dev code then you know hw it might get enabled.

Comment: Is there no property in the table itself to let you know they're on?

Comment: EF doesn't look into the data of the table but checks if configuration is enabled and _migration things exists to trigger the migration. It's the migration process that uses the data inside the migration table.